# Temp rating and insulation type of old nm sheathed cable

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker, appliances, nec, gauge

A family vacation home that we had someone build back in 1965 has a 200 amp service panel. A few of the breakers in my opinion are oddly sized for the loads that're on those dedicated ckts.

The hot water heater is on a **40 amp breaker** 240 V branch circuit which is oversized for water heaters. The Bradford-White water heater that was just installed is 4500 W. The water heater that was replaced was a Kenmore 3800 W. I asked the family member who was replacing the tank to measure the gauge of the copper wiring (the wires are solid copper) since we know the ckt breaker size. It came as a surprise that the wires measured (crudely measured with a wire stripper) **only 10 Awg**.

I started searching the net on temperature ratings, heat resistance, insulation types . . . anything I could dig up on the history of NM sheathed cable that might possibly explain why they ran 10 Awg with a 40 amp breaker for the water heater back in the 1960's. Could NM sheathed 90 deg C cable have been introduced for a brief time when the house was built?

The concern not only involves the 40 amp 240 volt circuit. I don't know what the manufacturer ratings are for a stove/oven that was installed (replaced) 5 yrs ago. It's wired to a **60 circuit breaker** that the electrican installed when the house was built. I have no idea what wire gauge size was installed. 3/C 4 Awg copper would be the correct size for a 60 amp breaker. yes/no?

I can't think of another reason there would be the mismatch of the 2/C 10 Awg and 40 amp circuit breaker other than that 90 deg C temperature and insulation type rated for 40 amps.

Note: the owner now within the family is having the 200 amp service panel replaced. I'll suggest the electrician installs all appropriate size breakers, e.g, stove/oven combo, water heater, built-in wall space heaters

Comment: Unless the stove/oven is quite big/restaurant size, 60 amps seems quite a bit   over.  Stoves/ovens usually use 40 amps.  It does seem like the person who put the breakers in thought bigger was better.   Are you sure the person who put the breakers in was licensed and knew code?  Should check if the stove and/or dryer circuits have been updated, back in 65 till 96 NEMA 10 type plugs/receptacles were allowed and are now known as not being safe.

Comment: @crip659. No, its not some huge Viking (restaurant type) range. Its just a small drop-in. And no, the builder didn't hire a non-certified electrician. The recently replaced stove/oven was taken there out of the owners primary residence and  was installed when his house was built by his builder. His primary residence was built before 1996 so it could be (may have) the NEMA 10 type plugs.

Comment: Why do you care what the reason was? Seems like what matters is do the various components meet code and are they safe/prudent according to current practice and knowledge. Seems plausible that the problematic main panel brand might be related, but once you change that, what's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own questions. The research on the NEC and the Underwriters Laboratories General Information on Electrical Equipment Directory are the sources. I'm aware I'm not citing the most recent up-to-date articles from the latest NFPA 70, National Electric Code, but I'm presenting (I believe) everything accurately nevertheless.

*Personal Caveat: I don’t have an image of the markings on the conductors that supports that the type of conductors are THHN. Also, the type of conductors are not marked typically. The claim is based on speculation.*

### [110.14( C )] Conductors must be sized to the equipment terminal temperature rating

[110.14 ( C ) (1) (a) (1)] Equipment 100 A and less

**Conductor – 60 Degree C**

So going to the 60 Degree Column for Copper under the NEC ampacity charts - **Table 310.16**

> What size THHN conductor is required for a 30 amp circuit?

The temp rating of THHN insulation is 90 Degree C. But because the equipment is less than 100 A, the conductor must be sized to the 60 Degree column and cannot be sized to 90 C unless listed and marked.

So the minimum size = 10 AWG rated 30 amps

---

[110.14 ( C ) (1) (a) (3)] Equipment 100 A and less

**Conductor – 75 Degree C**

So going to the 75 Degree Column for Copper under the NEC ampacity charts - **Table 310.16**

> What size THHN conductor is required for a 30 amp circuit when the terminals are rated 75 Degree C?

Conductors terminating on equipment rated 75 Degree C are sized with the ampacities listed in the 75 Degree temp column if the conductors have an insulation rating of at least 75 Degree C.

Since the equipment is rated 30 amps, the minimum size terminating on the water heater rated 75 Degree C is sized to 75 Degree ampacity **if both the breaker and the equipment are rated for 75 degree C**

Then the minimum size  = 10 AWG rated 35 amps

---

[110.14.(C) (2)] Terminals rated 90 Degree C

**Conductor – 90 Degree C**

I doubt that the thermal rating of 90 C terminal lugs evolved to become a recent introduction to the manufacturing industry.

The code states that when terminations are inside equipment (such as enclosed circuit breakers for example), follow the temperature rating identified on the **equipment labeling** instead of the rating of the terminal lug itself. Manufacturers commonly use 90 Deg C rated lugs (AL9CU as an example) **on eqpt rated only 60 Degree C or 75 Degree C**.  The use of the 90 Degree C rated lug does NOT allow the use of 90 Degree C conductors at the 90 Degree ampacity.

Furthermore, UL General information on Electrical Equipment Directory states the following about terminations:

*75 Degree C or 90 Degree C temp markings on a terminal does not in itself indicate that a 75 Degree C or 90 Degree C insulated wire can be used **unless the eqpt in which the terminals are installed is marked 75 Degree or 90 Degree C***

---

[110.14( C) (2)  Separately installed Connectors

- Terminals rated 90 Degree C

**Conductor – 90 Degree C**

Conductors terminating on **separately installed connectors** can be sized to the 90 Degree C column of Table 310.16 if the conductors and connectors are rated at least 90 Degree C.

Here, we’re not talking about terminating conductors on equipment. The reference is to terminating wire on a connector (specifically, separately installed connectors).

Conductors terminating on **equipment** rated 90 Degree C are sized with the ampacities listed in the 90 Degree temperature column if the conductors have an insulation rating of at least 90 Degree C, AND if the conductors terminate to connectors rated for 90 deg C, AND the lugs are not on equipment rated 75 degree C

> So what value is there then of 90 degree conductor insulation if the
> conductor insulation rating can’t use the 90 degree ampacity for
> conductor sizing ?

One reason is that the 90 Degree conductors based on 90 Degree ampacity might be used where they terminate at a terminal box or tap box using a 90 degree C termination and NOT directly in the equipment AND not directly in the service panel board.

The other reason for the value of 90 deg C conductors insulation might be that the 90 deg C ampacity rating is permitted to be used for ampacity “adjustment” or “correction”

Comment: You are allowed to tick it as well  after 24hrs.

Answer (score 5):

In 1965, NEC 1966 had yet to be adopted, and grounded wiring to 240V appliances was not in the code yet.  As such there's no (historic) code violation if those aren't grounded. Even in 1966 grounding was waived until 1996 for dryers and ranges.

We often see "NM" being used as an abbreviation for "non-metallic".  That is not valid. NM is *a very particular type* of non-metallic cable - others being, for example, SER, SEU, USE, MH feeder and UF.   NM and UF have a 60C thermal limit, limiting 6 AWG wire to 55A.  This also applies if the terminals or enclosures on either end are 60C thermal rated or not rated.

One spotter's guide for "Not NM" is a neutral wire which is a bare metal mesh wrapped around the two hot conductors.  That is SEU wire, and that is neutral not ground. (which is great news: you can retrofit ground, you can't retrofit neutral).

That said, I don't know exactly when NEC 240.4(D) became Code, but it puts its proverbial foot down and statutorially limits 10 AWG to 30A max regardless of all other issues.   (even if everything is 75-90C thermal rated, and 240.4(D) that did not exist, it's still only 35A wire).

So it sounds like your electrician, whatever else can be said about this person, was fond of intentionally oversizing breakers to reduce breaker trips and callbacks. This also reduces protection and is a violation of Code unless you have odd local amendments.  A lot of people learn a little and then get something in their head; they might have been looking at the motor rules which allow surprisingly large breakers (*because,* the overload protection is on the motor)... and thinking "why not everything else?"

1965 wire is sketchy, and so are 1965 breakers. So I would consider modernizing all, but don't use the previously chosen breaker sizes as "gospel".

Comment: So when NEC 240.4(D) became Code, it statutorially limited 10 AWG to 30A max (even if everything is 75-90C thermal rated, and if 240.4(D) did not exist back in '65, it's still only 35A wire.

Comment: Assuming 240.4(D) did not exist back in '65, then it's still only 35A wire. Then whether there could've ever back in 1965 had been 90 deg C sheathed wiring (house wiring)  on the market, it would not have been the justification for installing the over-sized breakers. A fair assumption ?

Comment: @A.G.Bell Still no, because to use the 90C rating, the terminals at both ends must also be rated 90C, and the enclosures (e.g. breaker box) must also be rated 90C.  That is essentially nonexistent in the consumer space *today*... and some older stuff wasn't even 75C. Also, 75-90C wire wasn't common back then.  You can see in Table 310.16 where wire evolved from TW to THW to THWN-2.

Answer (score 1):

For your water heater circuit, the most likely explanation is that the 40A breaker isn't original and was installed later to replace a 30A breaker.  The 30A would have been the correct size for both the wire and the load.  Even if the wire was 90C rated, there is no residential-grade panel or receptacle that I know of that has terminations rated higher than 75C.  Given that, there is no permutation that would have made the 40A breaker legal to my knowledge.

Speculating on why a 40A was installed to replace a 30A, it is possible that someone in the past was trying to (incorrectly) fix a tripping issue, or maybe the 40A breaker was simply close-at-hand and whoever installed it didn't have a 30A breaker handy or didn't care enough to find one.

As for the range circuit - the same situation sounds likely.  #6 AWG copper NM-B would require a 50A breaker (closest to the wire's 55A rating without going over).  A 60A breaker is one level higher than allowed, just like the water heater circuit.  Sounds like the previous owner had a pattern.

Comment: No, this is not the situation with the water heater breaker. I can say with 150% certainty that the 40 amp is the original breaker that was installed. Thank you for sharing that no residential grade panel or receptacle is rated higher than 70 deg. I wasn't aware of that. As to speculation on why a 40 amp breaker was originally installed. You may be correct that a 40 amp was the only size available. Same with the range circuit. The built-in the wall space heaters seem to be correctly sized with the loads and are wired with the proper wire size.

Comment: If the breaker is in fact original, then yep - the electrician just installed the wrong breakers, due to negligence, ignorance, convenience -  we'll never know.  Depending on the local authority, that likely *should have* failed inspection, but who's to say how stringent they were with inspections at the time.  My 2010-built Southern CA house was built with so many code violations it boggles my mind, but at the rate they were throwing houses up then, I'd be surprised if anyone was really looking that closely.

Comment: As a side note, this place was built out in the boonies when probably the local authority having jurisdiction weren't knowledgeable enough. I've pushed the owner to replace the service panel asap - ZINSCO. That replacement will also appropriate the correct size breakers for the WH and range

Comment: Wow - a Zinsco panel AND oversized breakers?  That's a keep-your-insurance-adjuster-on-retainer special.  Good plan pushing the owner to wholesale replace.

Comment: @crip659 what good stuff was left to the end? Were you maybe referring to the hype found on the internet about all Zinsco panels/ breakers ?https://forums.mikeholt.com/threads/zinsco-fpe-panels.149403/page-2#post-2341244

Comment: @A.G.Bell. Not to say they all eventually become slag, but it sure does explain the oversized breakers.  Installer probably knew they were "touchy" and decided to oversize to avoid getting called back.  Working in IT for a major HO insurance broker for 15 years, the top 5 terms that immediately caused rolled eyes (and a premium increase) from underwriters were Zinsco, Fed Pacific, Aluminum, Asbestos, and Pit Bull.